# Bazel function: git_repository vs new_git_repository?

Tags: bazel

What are the differences between functions `git_repository` and `new_git_repository`?

Can `new_git_repository` do everything `git_repository` does? If so, why do we have two separate functions?

(Was reading https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/repo/git.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you use `git_repository` if the underlying repository is already bazelized otherwise `new_git_repository`.

`new_git_repository` provides the attributes `build_file` and `build_file_content` whereas `git_repository` does not have those attributes.

For example [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) is already using Bazel as a build system (i.e. it provides `WORKSPACE` file in its root directory). To fetch it you can simply do:

```
# GoogleTest- Google Testing and Mocking Framework
git_repository(
    name = "googletest",
    commit = "703bd9caab50b139428cea1aaff9974ebee5742e",  # googletest v1.10.0
    remote = "https://github.com/google/googletest",
    shallow_since = "1570114335 -0400",
)
```

You can then easily use Google Test as an dependency in some `BUILD` file:

```
cc_test(
    name = "tests",
    timeout = "short",
    srcs = ["test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@googletest//:gtest_main", # Use GoogleTest as a dependency
    ],
)
```

`new_git_repository` is usually used if the underlying dependency is not bazelized. `new_git_repository` gives you the possibility to provide a `BUILD` file that is so to say injected in the repository under consideration. Besides this also a trivial `WORKSPACE` file is generated for the dependency. This way you can provide a `BUILD` file form outside to a git repo to make it working with the Bazel build system.

Example https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt is not bazelized. You can wirte a `fmt.BUILD` file with the following content:

```
cc_library(
    name = "fmt",
    srcs = [
        "include/fmt/args.h",
        "include/fmt/chrono.h",
        "include/fmt/color.h",
        "include/fmt/compile.h",
        "include/fmt/core.h",
        "include/fmt/format.h",
        "include/fmt/format-inl.h",
        "include/fmt/locale.h",
        "include/fmt/os.h",
        "include/fmt/ostream.h",
        "include/fmt/printf.h",
        "include/fmt/ranges.h",
        "include/fmt/xchar.h",
        #"src/fmt.cc", # No C++ module support
        "src/format.cc",
        "src/os.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "include/fmt/core.h",
        "include/fmt/format.h",
    ],
    includes = [
        "include",
        "src",
    ],
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Now you can use `new_git_repository` to provide (inject) the above build file, e.g.:

```
new_git_repository(
    name = "fmt",
    build_file = "//third_party:fmt.BUILD",
    ...
)
```

BTW: Also the workspace rule `local_repository` comes in two flavors: `local_repository` and `new_local_repository`. Again the new variant accepts also an external BUILD file. Older version of Bazel (< 0.29.0) had also `new_http_archive` - neverthless with an current version of Bazel (4.2.1) there is only `http_archive` that accepts also the attributes `build_file` and `build_file_content`.

Comment: Thanks, where should `third_party` folder be? Doesn't seem to find it next to the WORKSPACE file

Comment: Edit: This worked: `build_file = "fmt.BUILD",` which defaulted to look inside a folder called `external` instead of `third_party` ‍♂️

Comment: Bazel documentation shows that git_repository contains build_file field though: https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/git#git_repository-build_file

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to post an update to this question.

It looks like the Bazel team recently merged [this PR](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/pull/16064) that deprecated the use of `new_git_repository` in favour of just using `git_repository` to make it consistent with other rules like `http_archive` (see PR for more details).

This also explains why the [documentation](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/git) now shows the exact same description and attributes for both!